# Workflow: how to work on my Ubuntu laptop from my Mac desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, mac

I do most of my programming on my Ubuntu laptop, but there are times when I need to work on my Mac. I want to combine the two so that I am only working on my dual screen Mac, but I am able to edit the files on my laptop. I have many different programming projects that I want to work on. I want to be able to work on a project regardless of which computer I'm on.

I am open to many different solutions to this scenario.

Answer (score 9):

You could use a remote desktop program such as [VNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/) to access the other machine.

If you want to integrate the two side by side, you may be interested in [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/). You can hook one screen into the laptop, or just place the laptop beside one of the screens, and then connect them via the LAN.

> Synergy is Free and Open Source Software that lets you easily share
>   your mouse and keyboard between multiple computers, where each
>   computer has its own display. No special hardware is required, all you
>   need is a local area network. Synergy is supported on Windows, Mac OS
>   X and Linux. Redirecting the mouse and keyboard is as simple as moving
>   the mouse off the edge of your screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Macfuse http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/ is a very useful thing in these situations... it lets you mount a filesystem for any system you have SSH access to, and then edit it from the Mac.  I'm +1 on the previous answer too, because that may help more in your situation.

Also, remember that if you log in to the Ubuntu box over the network using ssh -X and then run some X app, it will display on your Mac. You did install the X server on the Mac, right? It's in the optional installs on your OS disc, or here: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget you can also just SSH into your laptop and edit files with vim. No extra software installs required.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the option of using [rsub/rmate to ssh tunnel](https://wrgms.com/editing-files-remotely-via-ssh-on-sublimetext-3/) and use your local text editor to edit remote files.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have them on the same network...

Install the X11 server on the Mac (used to be on developer disk, now it is in the store)

Open a terminal.  SSH into the ubuntu machine with your display exported back to the mac.  Start whatever app you want on the ubuntu machine, you'll use the mac display and keyboard/mouse but the ubuntu machine's CPU, RAM, hard drive, etc.

`ssh -Y username@ubuntu.ip.or.hostname`

Login, and start whatever app you want.

If you just want the Ubuntu machine's files and not the apps, you could install `sshfs` on the mac and mount your home directory on the Ubuntu machine over SSH - `mkdir /UbuntuHome` and then `sshfs user@ubuntu:/home /UbuntuHome`